# Compute $\pi_{3+k}(S^3)$ with $k\le 3$ using Steenrod squares

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, spheres, spectral-sequences, fibration

As an application of the theorem

> (**Serre**) The cohomology ring $\mathcal{H}^*(K(\mathbb{Z}_2,n);\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2[Sq^I(\iota_n)]$ where $\iota_n$ is a fondamental class of $\mathcal{H}^n(K(\mathbb{Z}_2,n);\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and $I$ is ammissible with excess less than $n$.

I find in **Mosher**'s book: *Cohomology operations and applications in homotopy theory*

The computing of $\pi_{3+k}(S^3)$ with $k\le 3$. In particular, using the map $$Sq^2(\iota_3):K(\mathbb{Z},3)\longrightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}_2,5),$$ he obtains a fibration $F_1\longrightarrow X_1\longrightarrow B$ where

- $X_1$ is the pull-back of $Sq^3(\iota_3)$ and the path-fibration $PK(\mathbb{Z}_2,5)\longrightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}_2,5)$
- $F_1=K(\mathbb{Z}_2,4)$
- $B=K(\mathbb{Z},3)$

After some calculation in the Serre spectral sequence associated to the fibration $F_1\longrightarrow X_1\longrightarrow B$, he find $\pi_{4}(S^3)$ and $\pi_{5}(S^3)$.

My question is, after computing the $H^*(X_1)$ how I can find this homotopy groups for $S^3$? I don't see this link.

Thanks all for answering

Comment: Care to give the precise reference?

Comment: page 123 of this book: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/moshtang.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they explain on p. 113, there is a map $S^3 \to K(\mathbb{Z}, 3)$, and the composite
$$
S^3 \to K(\mathbb{Z}, 3) \xrightarrow{Sq^2} K(\mathbb{Z}/2, 5)
$$
is zero, so there is a lift to a map $S^3 \to X_1$. This map induces an isomorphism on cohomology in dimensions up to 4, mono in dimension 5, so it induces an isomorphism on $\pi_4$.

Now the point is to continue this pattern: find a space $X_2$, a map $X_2 \to X_1$, and a lift $S^3 \to X_2$ which induces an isomorphism on cohomology in a larger range of dimensions. So you need to compute the cohomology of $X_1$ so as to know how to get a fibration $X_2 \to X_1 \to K(?, ?)$. Then you will know the homotopy groups of $X_2$ and they will agree with those of $S^3$ through dimension 5.

Comment: thank you, I guess that I have to understand better Serre class and $\mathcal{C}_p$ approximation theorem.

Comment: @Cris if you pretend that the prime 2 is the only one (which is how I try to live my life), then you can think of this as basically being the Hurewicz theorem: the map $S^3 \to K(\mathbb{Z}, 3)$ induces an isomorphism on (co)homology through a range, and so it also induces an isomorphism on $\pi_*$ through a range. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are constructed so that the isomorphism on (co)homology is in a wider range, and so the same is true for homotopy groups.

Comment: Why if I consider only the prime 2, is sufficient Hurewicz mod C? By it we know that there is a $\mathcal{C}_2$- isomorphism, but not that the homotopy groups are isomorphic..
Now I have two doubt: first, why I sufficently consider prime 2 and not the all prime? (to compute $\pi_4,\pi_5,\pi_6$ of $S^3$
Second, to conclude that $f$ induces a cohomology isomorphism, we need to compute through Serre S-S  the cohomology of $X_1$ and then?

Comment: @Cris In Mosher and Tangora's book, on page 112-113 it's mentioned that when they write $\pi_k$ they really mean the $2$-primary part of $\pi_k$. But, also, there's a result that says $\pi_i(S^3)$ has no $p$-torsion when $i < 2p$ and when $i=2p$ the $p$-torsion part is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, so for $i=4,5,6$ the only prime you need to consider is $2$ anyway.